# How to stretch a non-rectangular background

Tags: css

I am seeking to improve the following design for a question and answer page.

[image]

I want to change the shape of the orange backgrounds behind the question numbers to be a five-sided tag or arrow shape. I want the tags to expand horizontally to fit longer question numbers, but the angled sides need to retain the same angle regardless of how wide each tag is.

[image]

What’s the best way to implement this? Background images and the [sliding doors technique](https://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors/)?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nabla&family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 2em 10vw;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

h2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  h2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
  }
}

mark {
  background-color: #f26419;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <mark>Q8</mark>
  What does your mother yell at you when she’s angry?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q9</mark>
  Why are turtles green?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q10</mark>
  What is the biggest lie you've ever told? 
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q11</mark>
  If you could only watch one movie for the rest of your life, which one would it be?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation uses an absolutely positioned pseudo-element with an SVG background image to achieve the effect.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nabla&family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 2em 10vw;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

h2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  h2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1.5em;
  }
}

mark {
  background-color: #f26419;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 2px 0.2em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8PX;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative
}

mark::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 44 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 0 100 L 0 0 C 5.027 0 8.679 2.28 11.046 5.445 L 40.027 40 C 42.215 43.256 47.309 49.239 40.027 60 L 11.027 94.6 C 8.208 98.09 5.027 100 0 100 Z' style='stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(242, 100, 25);'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 1px);
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <mark>Q8</mark>
  What does your mother yell at you when she’s angry?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q9</mark>
  Why are turtles green?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q10</mark>
  What is the biggest lie you've ever told? 
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
<h2>
  <mark>Q11</mark>
  If you could only watch one movie for the rest of your life, which one would it be?
</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. </p>
```